# Call a function on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I would like to know how to call a function on a div in HTML and Javascript. How can I call the `capitalizestring()` function on the div? I need to capitalize the string

```
function capitalizestring(str){
   return str.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(function (i) {
        if (i.length > 2) {
            return i.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + i.substr(1);
        } else {
            return i;
        }
    }).join(' ');
}
```

```html
<div id="send">bank transfer</div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me can you elaborate at what event you want to call this function?

Comment: Do you need to capitalize the text in div?

Comment: you need to tell us **when** this should happen. You have to bind to an event to trigger the function: on focus on the div, on click, on hover, on focus loose... when? then you can trigger it easily

Comment: Under what event are you expecting this function call to occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capitalize the text in css

```html
<div id="send" style="text-transform: capitalize;">bank transfer</div>
```

Comment: Note that this makes the entire content uppercase, not the first letter of each word

Comment: Yes my bad for that :) i fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

```js
  function capitalizestring(str){
   return str.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(function (i) {
        if (i.length > 2) {
            return i.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + i.substr(1);
        } else {
            return i;
        }
    }).join(' ');
}

var elm = document.getElementById('send')
elm.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var currVal = elm.innerText;
   elm.innerText = capitalizestring(currVal)
});
```

```html
 <div id="send">bank transfer</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use css `text-transform: uppercase;`
this is ref [Link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-transform/#article-header-id-0).

```html
<div id="send" style="text-transform: uppercase;">bank transfer</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on when/how you want to activate the function you could use an `onchange` attribute to call the function when the value inside the `div` is changed, though it would usually be used in an `input field` rather than a `div`. Or you could use `onclick` to call the function when clicking on the `div`. If you want the function to be called once when the page is loaded, you can also call it inside a `<script>` tag.

```
<div id="send" onchange="capitalizestring()">bank transfer</div>
<div id="send" oncclick="capitalizestring()">bank transfer</div>
<script>capitalizestring();</script>
```

Comment: inline javascript is not the best way to do it. better a script at the bottom of the page or with a DOM ready listener before... see @Rajasekar answer for an example of what i mean